# Python - Efficiently calculate Manhattan distance between each pair of rows in two matrices

Tags: python, numpy

I have two matrices with the shapes `(AxN)` and `(BxN)` and I'd like to get a new matrix of `(AxB)` where each element is the Manhattan distance between each two rows.

I have tried to use [cdist](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.cdist.html), but in truth it is very slow, for example if we are talking about cosine distance, the following code takes like 4 seconds on the same data that `cdist` takes over two minutes

```py
dotted = matrix_a.dot(matrix_b.transpose())
matrix_a_norms = np.expand_dims(np.linalg.norm(matrix_a, ord=2, axis=1), axis=0)
matrix_b_norms = np.expand_dims(np.linalg.norm(matrix_b, ord=2, axis=1), axis=0)
norm_mat = matrix_a_norms.transpose().dot(matrix_b_norms)
cosine_distance = np.divide(dotted, norm_mat)
```

So I am wondering, is there any blazing-fast implementation for doing the same, only with Manhattan distance?

**EDIT**:

I've tried `sklearn`'s pairwise Manhattan and it  takes same time as `cdist`

**EDIT 2**:

Exact details

`A=14587`
`B=30228`
`N=300`

`dtype` is `float32`

With `sklearn.pairwise.manhattan_distances` / `cdist(metric='cityblock')` it takes about 135 seconds on average

Comment: What are the shape params for your use-case - `A,B,N`?

Comment: Updated post for `A,B,N`

Comment: Show your cdist usage? I can't replcate the same results with it when compared against your posted code.

Comment: `cdist(matrix_a, matrix_b, metric='minkowski', p=1)` and the posted code is about cosine similarity, it has nothing to do with the question it is there to emphasize that alternate ways can get much better performance than `cdist`. If this is what you are after try `cdist(matrix_a, matrix_b, metric='cosine')`

Comment: But cdist suggest `cdist(XA, XB, 'cityblock')` for Manhattan distances.

Comment: I know, its the same time, I used `minkowski` because I use the euclidean distance sometime and it is easier to change the `p` alone

Comment: In my tests, using `metric='cityblock'` is much faster than using `metric='minkowski', p=1`.

Comment: Well I'll try that tomorrow, I sure do hope you are right - how is it compared to `sklearn`?

Comment: These are the exacts, for `A=14587`, `B=30228` and `N=300` I get from `sklearn.pairwise.manhattan_distances` and from `cdist(metric='cityblock')` a mean of 135 seconds. `dtype` of both matrices is `float32`